# POST data not being sent in the right format from Angular 2 service but works correctly when sent from PostMan

Tags: javascript, angular, express

When the POST data is sent from the Angular 2 service like so:

```
  const data = new FormData();
        data.append('date', '12/01');
        data.append('weight', '170');

  return this.http.post(this.url + '/weight', data, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  });
```

The API (express app) console logs:

```
{ '------WebKitFormBoundary1SpZmi1Rt1eynOGJ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '"date"\r\n\r\n12/01\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary1SpZmi1Rt1eynOGJ\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="weight"\r\n\r\n170\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary1SpZmi1Rt1eynOGJ--\r\n' }
```

When sent from PostMan like so:

[image]

The API console logs:

```
{ date: '12/1', weight: '170' }
```

Which is the correct format. How to get it to work similarly from the Angular service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code snippet.

```
let data= new URLSearchParams();
data.set('date', '12/01');
data.set('weight', '170');

 return this.http.post(this.url + '/weight', data, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  });
```

OR try the following

```
let data= `date=${date}&weight=${weight}`
```

Comment: manually create data and test "let data= `date=${date}&weight=${weight}`";